# conditional image widget on wordpress

Tags: image, wordpress, widget

hi im writing because i have a n image that when you click it on it redirect to on link but when you are logged in  it should redirect to other link I tried with conditional widget plug in and many things so I need your help thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you building a theme or otherwise editing the php? Then you can use a `<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { ... } else { ... } ?>` construction.

Comment: I configured image widget plug in and put the link reference but when users are logged already it still points to the first lik and it should redirect to other link

Comment: I place in the situation when a user is not register you click in the image and it takes you to the register page but when you are register alreadi it takes you to the content

Answer (score 0):

I use  Logged In Conditional Text Widget to make what I want to make conditional banner redirection